# Android How to detect contact list is changed?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, contactscontract

I have implemented a ContentObserver, using this method I'm only able to be notified if a change occurs on a contact

but I don't know which contact has been added , deleted or updated ??

! Any suggestions ?  how do i know which particular contact is modified ?

i am getting all contact list by using following method .

```
    public void readContacts() {

    System.out.println("   reading contact ");
    String phoneNumber = null;
    Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String _ID = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID;
    String DISPLAY_NAME = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;
    String HAS_PHONE_NUMBER = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER;

    Uri PhoneCONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String Phone_CONTACT_ID = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID;
    String NUMBER = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER;

    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            null);

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contact_id = cursor
                    .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
            // int id =
            // Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
            // HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                output.append("\n First Name:" + name);

                System.out.println(" CONTACT NAME  : " + name);
                Contact_Name.add(name);

                // Query and loop for every phone number of the contact
                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                phoneCursor.moveToNext();

                phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                        .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);
                System.out.println(" CONTACT number  : " + phoneNumber);

                phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceAll("\\s", "");
                // phoneNumber = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length()
                // - 10);
                // System.err.println("Mobile no."+phoneNumber);
                Contact_Number.add(phoneNumber);

                phoneCursor.close();
            }
            output.append("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

and i am observing contact list is being some changed by regestring and using following code .

```
this.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, true, mObserver);

private ContentObserver mObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        final int currentCount = getContactCount();
        if (currentCount < mContactCount) {
            System.out.println("  Deleted contact");
        } else if (currentCount == mContactCount) {
            System.out.println("  upated contact");
        } else {
            System.out.println("  inserted contact");
        }
        mContactCount = currentCount;

    }

};
```

Comment: Why is the declaration of `mObserver` after the `registerContentObserver`?

Comment: @Manu  i had declared this perfectly in my code. here only i typed after registerContentObserver

Answer (score 2):

Check if the version is greater than the one you have already (for the current contact). This is fast and more accurate then the current process your are following, since `OnChange` is called for all the items (**delete**, **add** or **update**).

So counting the # of contacts doesn't make much sense because a contact would have been updated then deleted and new contact added. the count is same in this case.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#VERSION

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use this implementation for you Contacts array**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class ActiveList<T> extends ArrayList<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 870605912858223939L;
    transient private List<ActiveListListener<T>> listeners;

    public interface ActiveListListener<T> {
        void onAdd(T item);

        void onInsert(int location, T item);

        void onAddAll(Collection<? extends T> items);

        void onClear();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void clear() {
        super.clear();
        fireChangedEvent();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int size() {
        return super.size();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized T get(int index) {
        return super.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean add(T item) {
        boolean success = super.add(item);
        if (success) {
            fireAddEvent(item);
        }
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void add(int index, T item) {
        super.add(index, item);
        fireInsertEvent(index, item);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean addAll(int index, Collection<? extends T> items) {
        boolean success = super.addAll(index, items);
        if (success) {
            fireAddAllEvent(items);
        }
        return success;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> items) {
        boolean success = super.addAll(items);
        if (success) {
            fireAddAllEvent(items);
        }
        return success;

    }

    public synchronized void addListener(ActiveListListener<T> listener) {
        if (this.listeners == null) {
            listeners = Lists.newArrayList();
        }
        this.listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public synchronized void removeListener(ActiveListListener<T> listener) {
        if (this.listeners != null) {
            this.listeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    private void fireChangedEvent() {
        if (this.listeners == null)
            return;
        for (ActiveListListener<T> listener : listeners) {
            listener.onClear();
        }
    }

    private void fireInsertEvent(int location, T item) {
        if (this.listeners == null)
            return;
        for (ActiveListListener<T> listener : listeners) {
            listener.onInsert(location, item);
        }
    }

    private void fireAddEvent(T item) {
        if (this.listeners == null)
            return;
        for (ActiveListListener<T> listener : listeners) {
            listener.onAdd(item);
        }
    }

    private void fireAddAllEvent(Collection<? extends T> items) {
        if (this.listeners == null)
            return;
        for (ActiveListListener<T> listener : listeners) {
            listener.onAddAll(items);
        }
    }
}
```

**In your Activity or Adapter**

```
protected ActiveList.ActiveListListener<Contact> activeListListener = new ActiveList.ActiveListListener<Contact>() {
        @Override
        public void onAdd(Contact c) {
            // do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onInsert(final int location, final Contact c) {
            // do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onClear() {
            // do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onAddAll(List<Contact> cs) {
            // do something
        }
    };
```

**and in your Array**

```
((ActiveList<Contact>) this.contacts).addListener(activeListListener);
```

**See example** https://github.com/davidevallicella/UnivrApp/

Comment: it's a lengthy piece of code. How about using versions for the contacts http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns